# JDBC call function with custom type parameter

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a Postgres custom type as below:

```
create type custom_type as
(
    a  text,
    b   text,
    c boolean
);
```

And the function is as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(strings custom_type[]) RETURNS VOID
AS
$$
BEGIN

end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Now i have the following JDBC implementation as follows.

```
try (Connection connection = DataSource.getConnection()) {

        String call = "select test(?)";

        Array sqlArray = connection.createArrayOf("custom_type", new CustomTypeDTO[]{
                        new CustomTypeDTO("123456", "11221", "false"),
                        new CustomTypeDTO("123426", "113221", "false"),
                });

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(call)
        preparedStatement.setArray(1, sqlArray);
        preparedStatement.execute();
} catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here i get the following error

ERROR: malformed record literal: "main.java.test.dto.CustomTypeDTO@4802796d"
Detail: Missing left parenthesis.